# How to make a value in C++ undefined?

Tags: c++

I was working on a little program that would take a number as input, check if it's bigger than the variable `largest` and check if it's smaller than the variable `smallest`. Those variables were supposed to keep track of, well, the largest and smallest value entered so far.

The only problem is that both values start off holding garbage values, so I tried to assign both to zero, but when I do so the program breaks, because when I enter five for example it's supposed to be largest and smallest value but instead C++ assigns zero to the smallest value.

```
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    double a, largest, smallest;
    while (std::cin >> a) { 
        if (largest < a)
            largest = a;
         if (smallest > a)
            smallest = a;

        std::cout << "The smallest so far: " << smallest <<'\n';
        std::cout << "The largest so far: " << largest << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to set `smallest` to the *largest* possible value, and `largest` to the *smallest* possible value:

```
double largest = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest();
double smallest = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

If you actually want to make a variable have no value, that's what [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) is for. `std::optional<double> largest;` would be initialized to have no value at all.

Comment: I tend to use `NaN` instead of `optional<double>`. It's convenient and already there.

Answer (score 2):

With std::optional. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional
The std::optional can have, or not, a value. At start, it hasn't value.
You can use it to handle the state "don't have yet a value assigned"

Here an example with your case :

```
#include<iostream>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    double a;
    std::optional<double> largest, smallest;
    while (std::cin >> a) {
        if (largest.has_value() == false || largest < a)
            largest = a;
        if (smallest.has_value() == false || smallest > a)
            smallest = a;

        std::cout << "The smallest so far: " << smallest.value() << '\n';
        std::cout << "The largest so far: " << largest.value() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Evg 1) yes, but I prefered wrote .has_value() == false to be more understable by the author.
2) no need for the * in the < or > : 
`template< class T, class U >
constexpr bool operator>( const optional<T>& opt, const U& value );`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_cmp

Answer (score 1):

With a subtle (but significant) change in the two comparisons, one could initialize `largest` and `smallest` to `NaN` ([not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)) values and then take advantage of the fact that **all** [comparisons to `NaN` values return false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/10871073):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double a, largest = std::nan(""), smallest = std::nan("");
    while (std::cin >> a) {
        if (!(a <= largest))
            largest = a;
        if (!(a >= smallest))
            smallest = a;

        std::cout << "The smallest so far: " << smallest << '\n';
        std::cout << "The largest so far: " << largest << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is not really a significant improvement on the [answer provided by cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62360273/10871073), but I'm nonetheless offering it as an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the behaviour you see is that `largest` and `smallest` are uninitialised, and then their values are accessed in the tests `(if largest < a)` and `if (smallest > a)` respectively.     Accessing their values (which is necessary in any comparison) then causes undefined behaviour.

One fix is to ensure their values are initialised before the first attempt to access their values.

```
if (std::cin >> a)
{
    smallest = largest = a;

    do
    { 
        if (largest < a)      // Safe since variables are initialised
           largest = a;
        else if (smallest > a)
           smallest = a;
        std::cout << "The smallest so far: " << smallest <<'\n';
        std::cout << "The largest so far: " << largest << '\n';
    }  while (std::cin >> a);
}
```